# Playing audio.mpd and video.mpd together in dash.js

Tags: dash.js, mp4box

For MPEG DASH streaming, I have audio.mpd and video.mpd separately for a video.mp4 file generated using following command.

```
MP4Box -dash 5000 -frag 5000 -rap -bs-switching no -profile dashavc264:live -segment-name ./video/$2_segment_ -out ./mpds/$2_video.mpd $2.mp4#video

MP4Box -dash 5000 -frag 5000 -rap -bs-switching no -profile dashavc264:live -segment-name ./audio/$2_segment_ -out ./mpds/$2_audio.mpd $2.mp4#audio
```

Each mpd plays separately in dash.js. Is it possible to play them together using dash.js?

Or is there any way to merge both using MP4Box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 options:

1. MPD are XML. So you can easily post-process them to merge. Practically the MPD should be nearly identical. Insert both `<AdaptationSet>`s in a new MPD under `<Period>`.
2. Alternately execute the following command-line to make it in one pass: `MP4Box -dash 5000 -frag 5000 -rap -bs-switching no -profile dashavc264:live -segment-name $2_segment_ -out ./mpds/$2_video.mpd $2.mp4#video:baseURL=video $2.mp4#audio:baseURL=audio`

Comment: Hi this command generates a segment_init.mp4 file and segment_[1 to n].m4s files. Is it possible to generate init file as segment_0.mp4 and other files as segment_[1 to n].m4s

Comment: `segment_$Number$$init=0$.m4s` is the closest to your request. Please have a look at https://github.com/gpac/gpac/issues/458 and don't hesitate to contribute to this enhancement!